# iPython DF pattern validation

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to identify patterns in a DF column: a streak of 4 zeros (represent rainy days) followed by 1 (dry day) in column "dry day". When this pattern is identified, 1 is to be marked in column "streaky". The result is not consistent: there are correct matches (2012-10-23) as well as false ones (2012-10-17). What goes wrong?

[image]

```
for i in range(0,2641): 
    if sum(X2.iloc[i:(i+4),4]) ==0 and X2.iloc[(i+5),4] ==1: 
        X2.iloc[(i+5),16] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a test dataframe (with only the columns necessary and 16 rows) and **I am getting the expected results.**

I also manually created an "expected" column to compare the "actual" (streaky) column to.

I am using Python 3.8.3 64-bit and running in VSCode

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date':  ['2012-10-13', '2012-10-14', '2012-10-15', '2012-10-16', '2012-10-17', '2012-10-18','2012-10-19', '2012-10-20', '2012-10-21', '2012-10-22','2012-10-23','2012-10-24' , '2012-10-25','2012-10-26', '2012-10-27', '2012-10-28', '2012-10-29' ],
    'dry day': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    'expected':['', '', '', '',  '', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', '1', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']
    }

X2 = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Date','dry day', 'expected'])
X2["actual"] = ""

for i in range(0,12): 
    if sum(X2.iloc[i:(i+4),1]) ==0 and X2.iloc[(i+5),1] ==1: 
        print(str(X2.iloc[i+5,0]) + " : is Streaky" )
        X2.iloc[(i+5),3] = 1
    else:
        X2.iloc[(i+5),3] = 'none'

print(X2)
```

[image: Results as Expected]

Comment: I am getting the warning: "SettingWithCopyWarning:A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." probably here is the answer: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ - as I was using a subset/ copy of the original pd DF. Thanks for checking the code/ logic!